# Rename username label on woocommerce login page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i want to rename [username label](https://snag.gy/5rZpCk.jpg) "Username or email' on woocommerce login page, is there any working hook to achieve this,

```
function login_function() {
add_filter( 'gettext', 'username_change', 20, 3 );
function username_change( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) 
{
    if ($text === 'Username') 
    {
        $translated_text = 'customLoginName';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

}
add_action( 'login_head', 'login_function' );

Comment: You can [Override woocommerce templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) … This can be done editing [`myaccount/form-login.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.4/templates/myaccount/form-login.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is not any hook for change Username Or email label change but yes you can put in your theme /woocommerce/auth/form-login.php for override default plugin form.

and you can replace label text in form-login.php by finding below line.

```
<label for="username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
```