# Change field label text on Woocommerce login form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gettext, account

This Question is similar to [Rename username label on woocommerce login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51553130/rename-username-label-on-woocommerce-login-page)

I am trying to change the Label "Username or email address" to "Your registered email address"

[image: See screenshot where I am trying to change the label]

I am trying to do this without modifying the form-login.php template file.

So far I tried the below code:

```
function wppb_change_text_login( $translated_text, $text ) {
    //Login page
    $original_text = 'Username or email address';
    $new_text = 'Your registered email address';
    if ( $text == $original_text ) {
        $translated_text = $new_text;
    }
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wppb_change_text_login', 30, 2 );
```

However, I understand that gettext is very resource intensive function and I was wondering what changes should I make to make these changes be restricted to my-account page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code will work if you add `return $translated_text;` at the end in your function **as in any filter hook it's mandatory to return the filtered value.**

To restrict this function to my account registering form you will use the following conditions:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wppb_change_text_login', 10, 3 );
function wppb_change_text_login( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    // Only on my account registering form
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_account_page() ) {
        $original_text = 'Username or email address';

        if ( $text === $original_text )
            $translated_text = esc_html__('Your registered email address', $domain );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. this was the only version of code that worked for me as of July 2020.

Answer (score 2):

For rename Label "Username or email address" to "Your registered email address" Please add following function into your theme function.php

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'register_text'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'register_text'  );
function register_text( $translated ) {
     $translated = str_ireplace(  'Username or Email Address',  'Your registered email address',  $translated );
     return $translated;
}
```

I have tested the above function with storefront theme and its working for me please check the screenshot https://prnt.sc/m25hwz